# apache start error (trying to migrate from svn to git)

Tags: apache, svn

```
[ticksystem@fast svn]$ apachectl status

* httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
  Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2016-12-29 12:15:46 EST; 3min 7s ago
    Docs: man:httpd(8)
          man:apachectl(8)
 Process: 11321 ExecStop=/bin/kill -WINCH ${MAINPID} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Process: 11319 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Main PID: 11319 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Dec 29 12:15:46 fast.tdi.net httpd[11319]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
Dec 29 12:15:46 fast.tdi.net httpd[11319]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
Dec 29 12:15:46 fast.tdi.net httpd[11319]: no listening sockets available, shutting down
Dec 29 12:15:46 fast.tdi.net httpd[11319]: AH00015: Unable to open logs
Dec 29 12:15:46 fast.tdi.net systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 29 12:15:46 fast.tdi.net kill[11321]: kill: cannot find process ""
Dec 29 12:15:46 fast.tdi.net systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Dec 29 12:15:46 fast.tdi.net systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
Dec 29 12:15:46 fast.tdi.net systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
Dec 29 12:15:46 fast.tdi.net systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a closer look at the log:

```
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80 

(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
```

These events mean that the IP inteface or port 80 is unavailable, is already in use or blocked. In case of `OS 98`, it should be the port.